# Short horror film about about a vampire woman who kills a man who followed her home at night

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror, vampire, short-film

I watched a short horror film on Shorts TV years ago about a woman followed home at night from a restaurant or bar. The man follows her all the way into a gondola / travel lift. When the lift reaches the other side, the woman steps out and has killed the man. I think she drank his blood but it is not shown just implied. I do not think there was any dialogue, but I think it took place outside the United States.

It was only around 5 minutes long. I watched it in 2017, and think it was made around the same time, maybe a few years before.

Comment: Have you not thought ot any additional details to add in the last ten months of looking? https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/pvwyys/tomtmovie2000s_short_film_about_vampire_woman/

Comment: On the other forum post, someone suggested the short film *A Girl Walks Home Alone At Night*. Have you already rejected that?

Comment: @Valorum that movie is 1 hour 41 minutes long (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2326554/), not a short at all.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - Based on an 11 minute short film that was shown on Shorts TV

Comment: @Valorum, wow, even 8 mins imdb.com/title/tt2062469. So just post the answer, it fits anyway.

Comment: It is definitely not A Girl Walks Home Alone at Night. I think it was black and white like the full-length film, but the one I'm looking for was in color.

Comment: I wish I had more to go on, but I can't remember the name at all. I am just hoping to find someone else who may have seen it. I have also been searching through imdb horror shorts around the same year with no luck yet.